# How to display progress when we run action using ant with curl

Tags: php, magento, curl, ant

My sample code is.

```
<target name="retrieve-userdata" depends="test-src">
    <echo message="start the process for fetch region and event"/>
    <exec executable="curl">            
        <arg value='http://localhost/magento/index.php/facebook/index/test' />
    </exec>
    <echo message="end the process for fetch region and event"/>
</target>
```

When we run this ant, this

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/facebook/index/test
```

action is call and executes this action. In which, loop execute many time and fetch user facebook event.

So we want to display each event name at console when loop is execute in this action.

Please kindly help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: we want to display progress when run ant.

Comment: Ant is usually used for build and deploy, what you describe sounds like the operation of your system.  Why are you using Ant here?

Comment: @martinclayton Ant also used to run php action via curl. I add my Ant code in question. So when i run this ant with action, we want to disply progress for each activity that process under php action.

Answer (score 1):

I think You can use **[splash](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/splash.html)** to display progress.

check the following example, hope this will help:

```
<target name="retrieve-userdata" depends="test-src">
     <splash progressRegExp="Progress: (.*)%" showduration="0" displayText="Test text"/>
     <echo>Progress: 10%</echo>
     <exec executable="cmd">
        <arg value="/c" />
        <arg value="c:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php" />
        <arg value=" facebook/index/test" />
    </exec>
     <echo>Progress: 50%</echo>
     <!-- task 2 -->
     <echo>Progress: 70%</echo>
     <!-- task n -->
     <echo>Progress: 100%</echo>
     <sleep seconds="2"/>
</target>
```

In your file put `ob_implicit_flush(1);` this line to display output immediately into console

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to  get url, ant has a specific task for it. [Get](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html)

This also has feedback using dots.

See example from the site..

```
 <get src="http://www.apache.org/dist/ant/KEYS" 
    dest="KEYS" 
    verbose="true"
    usetimestamp="true"/>
```